# Generalizing JSON serialization classes instead of using specific classes to repreasent JSON file

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a set of JSON files as structured as below .

```
{
    "client":
    {
        "Home": { "minVersion": "12", "tested": true },
        "About": { "minVersion": "12", "tested": true }, 
        "MoreInfo": { "minVersion": "13", "tested": true }, 

    },

    "server":
    {
        "backendVersion": { "minVersion": "1.2" },
        "DBversion": { "minVersion": "1.2" }
    }
}
```

I understand deserializing these as it is using classes to represent the JSON files can be done which is straight forward but what I am trying to do has a layer of complexity above . Is it possible to implement so to get the required values without specifically creating classes for each.

Like for an example using this JSON I want to get a List of the keys under "Client" which is Home , About and  MoreInfo and I also want to store the minVersion for Home  , minVersion for About , minVersion for MoreInfo

If it helps all these particular JSON files will have a standard structure as specified below

```
{
    "<Client>":
    {
        "<Name>": { "minVersion": "<Version>" },

    },

    "<server>":
    {
        "<Name>": { "minVersion": "<Version>" }
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if anyone has an idea as to how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to Create Concrete classes, then you could use `AnonymousType` for Deserializing the Data.You could then retrive the required information from the deserialzied object.

```
var versionType = new {minVersion=string.Empty,tested=false};
var anonymousType = new { client= CreateDictionary(versionType),server= new Dictionary<string,Version>()};
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anonymousType);;
var client = result.client;
```

Where CreateDictionary is defined as

```
Dictionary<string,T> CreateDictionary<T>(T sourceType)
{
    return new Dictionary<string,T>();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

You could also use Linq to query the Json. For example,

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var result = jObject["client"].Select(x=>x.ToObject<JProperty>())
                              .Select(x=> new 
                                       {
                                          Name = x.Name, 
                                          MinVersion = x.Value["minVersion"],
                                          Tested = x.Value["minVersion"]
                                       });
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer 
I was I was able to work around and fulfill my objective using the anonymous type approach , so I will mark this answer as correct. btw The answer usnig linq did not work as the values were not getting assigned to the variables . 
Thanks again

Comment: @Devin Glad to help you. I have updated the output i received using Linq. If you could share the error/issue you faced with linq, may be we could solve that as well

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create classes, you can deserialize it to a dynamic object using Newtonsoft.JSON and interrogate it:

```
dynamic myObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var minVersion = myObj["client"]["Home"]["minVersion"];
```

Cast your types as you see fit.

If you want to get all of the `Keys` from your objects and iterate through them, you could do something like:

```
var client = myObj["client"];
var propertyNames = client.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
foreach(var property in propertyNames) {
    var minVersion = client[property]["minVersion"];
    Console.WriteLine($"Client[{property}] Min Version : {minVersion}");
}
```

Comment: Hi
Thank you for the reply but I am  getting an 

the error **Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type** when I tried to use the second part to iterate through the JSON key 

I also tried to modify your answer so to achieve the following objective

Comment: To go into the Save the name "Home" as a variable and use that Variable to get the minVersion of Home but once again was stuck with the part of getting the Name. Is there any way I can maybe store the names Home , About , MoreInfo in something . When I debug I can see these stored as chileTokens but was not able to access those values 

would really appreciate some more help on this , but using dynamic object to achieve my objective looks very promising.